# Binomial expansion of cube root

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Could anyone guide me to expand $$\sqrt[3]{\frac{3x+2}{x-3}}$$ for a binomial expansion up to $x^3$?

Comment: $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{\frac{3 x+2}{x-3}},f'(x)=-\frac{11}{3 (-3 x-2)^{2/3} (3-x)^{4/3}},f''(x)=\frac{22 (9 x-5)}{9 (-3 x-2)^{5/3} (3-x)^{7/3}},f^{(3)}(x)=-\frac{22 (27 x (9 x-10)+317)}{27 (-3 x-2)^{8/3} (3-x)^{10/3}}$

Comment: $f(0)=\sqrt[3]{-\frac{2}{3}},f'(0)=\frac{11 \sqrt[3]{-\frac{1}{3}}}{9\ 2^{2/3}},f''(0)=-\frac{55 \sqrt[3]{-\frac{1}{3}}}{81\ 2^{2/3}},f^{(3)}(0)=\frac{3487 \sqrt[3]{-\frac{1}{3}}}{1458\ 2^{2/3}}\quad \sqrt[3]{\frac{3 x+2}{x-3}}=\frac{3487 \sqrt[3]{-\frac{1}{3}} x^3}{8748\ 2^{2/3}}-\frac{55 \sqrt[3]{-\frac{1}{3}} x^2}{162\ 2^{2/3}}+\frac{11 \sqrt[3]{-\frac{1}{3}} x}{9\ 2^{2/3}}-\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{3}}+O(x^4)$

Answer (score 1):

Write it as $$2^{1/3}(\frac {3}{2}x+1)^{1/3}(-1)(1-\frac {x}{3})^{-1/3} $$ i have taken cuberrot of $-1$ as only $-1$ ignoring  complex rootsm now use binomial expansion for any rational number and for negative index.

Comment: Will the expansion converge?

Comment: No i didnt think about it as op wants only the coefficient of $x^3$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{\frac{3x+2}{x-3}}$.

Thus, $f(0)=-\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{3}}$, $f'(0)=-\frac{11}{9\sqrt[3]{12}}$, $f''(0)=\frac{55}{81\sqrt[3]{12}}$, $f'''(0)=-\frac{3487}{1458\sqrt[3]{12}}$

and the rest for you.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{3x+2}{x-3}}=\left(\frac {3(x-3)+11}{x-3}\right)^{\frac 13}=3^\frac 13\left(1+\frac {11}{3(x-3)}\right)^{\frac 13}=\cdots$$

Expansion converges when $|\frac {11}{3(x-3)}|<1$, i.e. $x>6$ or $x<-\frac 23$.